# How can I show that if $p^3$ divides $n^2$ then $p^2$ divides n? Can I generalise it?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

I found this question in a textbook and I thought about using FTA but I couldn't prove it 'rigourously'.
I'm also interested if there's a generalisation of this, like the powers being different than 2 or 3.

(n being a natural number and p is prime.)

Comment: I and others answered this a while back, and I generalized it. I'll try to find it.

Comment: Prove more generally that if $p^3\mid ab$ then either $p^2\mid a$ or $p^2\mid b.$

Comment: Who is downvoting this and the answers?

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

Let the highest exponent of $p$ that divides $n$ be $a$ where integer $n\ge0$

$p^3|n^2\implies2a\ge3\implies a\ge1.5\implies a\ge2$ as $a$ is an integer

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$n = p^a b$
where
$p \not\mid b$.

If
$p^3 | n^2$ then,
since $n^2 = p^{2a}b^2$,
$2a \ge 3$.
Therefore
$a \ge 2$,
so $p^2 | n$.

More generally,
suppose
$p^m | n^k$.
Since
$n^k = p^{ak}b^k$,
$m \le ak$
so
$a \ge \frac{m}{k}
$
so,
since $a$ is an integer,
$a \ge \lceil \frac{m}{k} \rceil
$.

This is the case
$m=3, k=2$.

Answer (score 0):

$\begin{align}{\rm By }\ \color{#c00}{\rm E}={\rm Euclid's\ Lemma\!:\ }\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  &p\mid \color{#0a0}{p^{\large 3}\!\mid n^{\large 2}} \overset{\color{#c00}{\rm E}}\Rightarrow\, p\mid n,\ \ \text{so cancelling }\ \color{#0a0}{p^{\large 2}}\\ 
\overset{\large\color{#0a0}{(\ \ )/p^2}}\Longrightarrow \ &\color{#0a0}{p\mid(n/p)^{\large 2}}\overset{\color{#c00}{\rm E}}\Rightarrow\,p\mid n/p\,\overset{\times\, p}\Rightarrow\, p^{\large 2}\mid n \end{align}$

To generalize it - rather that using Euclid's Lemma to "peel off" one prime at a time as above - it is more efficient to simply compare powers of primes in their unique prime factorizations.

Comment: This is meant to illustrate the use of Euclid's Lemma, since the approach by prime factorization has already been given in prior answers.